# 第一木曜日 : Which Thursday of the month is it?

Tags: words

When you say : 第一木曜日, does it mean the first Thursday of the month? Or does it mean Thursday of the first week of the month?

For instance, if we talk about October 2015, would 第一木曜日 be October 1st or October 8th?

[image: OCT2015]

Comment: I wonder what makes you think it might be the latter?

Comment: Because of some JLPT cram exam question based on a schedule with 第一, 第二... dates and which correct answer left me puzzled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would mean the first Thursday of the month. In October 2015, 第一木曜日 is October 1st. The 8th of October would be 第二木曜日.

[Here's](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1376925763) a question on Chiebukuro from someone who was mixed up with a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you. Moreover, if　I get your link correctly, 2015年10月の第1週　would actually start on 10/01 (and only have 3 days), which I would not call "first week of October" in my native language